# can't open excel file from browser

Tags: excel, sharepoint-2010

only on my pc i have message when try to open xlsx file in excel

> To open this book, your computer must have the version of Microsoft Excel and Web browser with support for open files directly from Excel.

i have installed ms office 2010 pro+ (including excel), i was try make this action from firefox 3.6.4-3.6.6 and internet explorer 8, any other pc in network can open successfully and software ion this pc's is same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

reinstall of office was very helpfull